# Modifying a String (char array)

Tags: c, arrays, char, c-strings, strcpy

I am trying to modify a string in C language

```
    char signal_cat[8]; 

        if (k == 1) {
            strcpy_s(signal_cat, "HPHA",6);             //why cant I change char array (string) values???
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            strcpy_s(signal_cat, "Normal",6);
        }

        printf("Original signal category: %s \n", signal_cat);
```

When I run this it shows an exception "Unhandled exception at 0x7BEBF71D (ucrtbased.dll) in Lab3Parti.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000006"

I have tried

```
signal_cat = "HPHA";
```

too, but an error shows "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: You got those parameters the wrong around. It's the destination, then the size of the destination, and then the source.

Comment: Didn't you get compiler warnings? If so, consider them as errors.

Comment: Note that `strcpy_s()` is a *de facto* non-portable, Microsoft-only extension.  `strcpy()` is **NOT** "deprecated" in any manner by anyone other than Microsoft, and `strcpy_s()` being "safer" is arguable at best.

Comment: Yet another case where `strcpy` was simple and correct whereas adding in "safer" version with extra arguments causes problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified an invalid order of arguments. A call of strcpy_s should look like

```
strcpy_s(signal_cat, sizeof( signal_cat ), "HPHA" );
```

Otherwise use the standard C function `strcpy` like

```
strcpy( signal_cat, "HPHA" );
```

provided that the array signal_cat has enough space to accommodate the string literal.

Or you can use another standard function `strncpy`

```
strncpy( signal_cat, "HPHA", sizeof( signal_cat ) );
signal_cat[sizeof( signal_cat )-1] = '\0';
```

As for this statement

```
signal_cat = "HPHA";
```

then arrays do not have the assignment operator. They are non-modifiable lvalues.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Visual Studio to compile your C code?

If you are and the compiler is forcing you to use `strcpy_s()` instead of `strcpy()`, you can still use the standard library function `strcpy()` by defining the following macro at the top of your source file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

The actual problem in your code is that you are giving the arguments to strcpy_s() in the wrong order. Check the function's prototype to provide the arguments in the correct order.

Answer (score -2):

What is strcpy_s?   Do you have a prototype for it in your code (ie. have you included the correct files for declarations?)  What are its arguments, and why are you using it?

You are obviously learning C; it is not in your best interest to start with some vendors proprietary (and often bizarre) extensions?   Learn the language, learn its established (standard) interfaces, then, if absolutely necessary, endure some vendors twisted extensions is a good process to follow:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char signal_cat[8]; 
  strncpy(signal_cat, "HPHA", sizeof signal_cat);
  printf("%s\n", signal_cat);
  strncpy(signal_cat, "Normal", sizeof signal_cat);
  printf("%s\n", signal_cat);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `strncpy` is not a somewhat safer version of `strcpy`. `strncpy` may leave you with a non NUL terminated string....

Comment: Actually `strncpy` should __never__ be used, it's a leftover from the early days and it should never have made it into string.h in the first place.

Comment: Not Never, it should be used with caution as it performs a very precise function which is often misinterpreted.   strlcpy() is the better generic, but solves a different problem and has *only* been in use for 20 or so years.

Comment: `strncpy`is basically useless.

Comment: "which is often misinterpreted" - as in this answer